# Node Js Import non-module.exports script

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm wondering how to import scripts to main app in NodeJS, just as you would in the browser.

I know that usgin `require` you can define `module.exports` in your script and have your functions exported. But I'm creating objects that I would like to be global. I'll give an example:

**`MAIN APP`**

```
require('./objects.js');
var smth = 234;
var obj = new ObjectDefElsewhere(smth);
obj.doSmth();
```

**`OBJECTS.JS`**

```
function ObjectDefElsewhere(val){
    this.val = val;

    this.doSmth = function(){
        console.log(this.val);
    }
}
```

Instead of having to go the usual

`module.exports : {objDefElsewhere: ObjectDefElsewhere}`

and having the require look like

`var Objects = require('objects.js'); new Objects.ObjDefElsewhere();`

Thanks!

Comment: Globals are no good. But you don't need to export an object with properties, you can also export the `ObjectDefElsewhere` constructor itself

Comment: you mean by putting `module.exports = ObjectDefElsewhere` ? But what If i defined 2+ constructors in one file. I was wondering because I wanted to build a game, and thought of making different files for different types of objects. Ex: file `Enemies.js` would provide constructors: `Zombie()`, `Warrior()`, `Ninja()` etc... and file `Weapons.js` would provide `Sword()`, `Bow()` etc...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. For multiple exports, you may of course use an object (and you really should do that, instead of polluting the global scope)

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'll do then!